# call function or construct data in runtime

Tags: haskell

Is there a possibility to construct data in runtime ? I mean something like "read" function, but which applies [(field name, value)]. Let's say I have

```
data Street = Street String
data City = City String
data ZipCode = ZipCode String

data Address = Address {
      street :: Street,
      city :: City,
      zipCode :: ZipCode
}
```

I want to have a function like:

```
genericConstructor :: (DataConstructable a) => String -> [(String, a)] -> a
```

So I can use it like this:

```
genericConstructor "Address" [("street", Street "Baker"), 
                              ("city", City "London"),
                              ("zipCode", ZipCode "12345")] :: Address
```

I don't want any boilerplate code, looking for anything similar to Reflection API for Java.
Currently looking at Data.Data and Data.Typeable modules though don't see how I can achieve it.

The purpose of all of this is to create a binding between some data format and haskell data structures.

Comment: Why does this need to be a bespoke type? Why not just use something like a hashtable or Data.Map that can map a string to another string?

Comment: I thought about using a Map as well, but to me it's very unsatisfying to keep all your data as Strings when you can have bespoke types.  Although the Haskell record system is much nicer to work with if you use a lenses module.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something close to what you're asking for.

```
import Data.Data
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Maybe

data City = City String deriving (Data, Typeable, Show, Eq)
data Street = Street String deriving (Data, Typeable, Show, Eq)

data Addr = Addr {
  city :: City
 ,street :: Street} deriving (Show, Eq, Data, Typeable)

class Foo a where
  genericConstr :: [(String,Dynamic)] -> a

instance Foo Addr where
  genericConstr = buildAddr

lf ls nm = fromMaybe (error $ nm ++ " not found") (lookup nm ls >>= fromDynamic)

buildAddr ls = Addr {city = lf ls "city", street = lf ls "street"}
```

Load this, and in ghci:

```
*Foo> genericConstr [("street", toDyn (Street "Baker")), ("city", toDyn (City "London"))] :: Addr
Addr {city = City "London", street = Street "Baker"}
```

This seems like a lot of work to me, though.  This is tricky because Haskell requires all types to be resolved at compile time; in this case you're trying to create types with run-time information (e.g. the string "Address").  This is possible, but you'll be fighting the type system at every step.  I agree with Jason that using a parser is probably a better approach.

Comment: With a bit of GADT "magic", you can have a map with dependently-typed entries.  Dependent types seem quite a bit cleaner to me than Data.Dynamic for this sort of thing, because they can statically enforce that, e.g., you don't try to put an Int into the "city" field.  It's not really ready for release, but I have an implementation of a dependently-typed finite map type in a darcs repo at http://code.haskell.org/~mokus/dependent-map if anyone is curious what such a thing might look like.  It depends on another unreleased package which is in another darcs repo in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem with your sceme is that with

```
genericConstructor :: (DataConstructable a) => String -> [(String, a)] -> a
```

all the 'arguments' would have to be of the same constructable type. Therefore, you would need something along the lines of

```
genericConstructor :: (DataConstructable a) => String -> [forall b. DataConstructable b => (String, b)] -> a
```

which I'm not entirely sure how to do, I must admit.

Would it not be easier just to parse everything from the data format string?

Comment: The type signature `Data a => String -> [(String, forall b. Data b=>b)] -> a` worked for me, although it did require ImpredicativeTypes.  I think the correct type signature for this application would be `forall a. Data a=> String -> [(String,String)] -> Maybe a`, but I agree a parser would be the better approach.

Comment: It did warn me that ImpredicativeTypes types are being depreciated so I thought there might be a safer alternative.

Comment: Currently there's no planned replacement for ImpredicativeTypes AFAIK; I wouldn't write new code that relies upon it.